# - , *, / operators not working on my basic calculator (javafx)

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I'm working on this basic calculator project using javafx and fxml on eclipse. + operators work perfectly fine, but the /, -, * always gives an output of zero. Can't figure out the problem

**Here is the class that process the input :**

```
public class MainProcess {
    @FXML
    public Label result;
   
    private long num1 = 0;
    private long num2 = 0;
    private String operator = "";
    
    private boolean start = true;
    private Calculation model = new Calculation();
    
    @FXML
    public void processNumbers(ActionEvent event) {
        if (start) 
        {
            result.setText("");
            start = false;
        }
        
        String value = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();
        result.setText(result.getText() + value);
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void processOperators(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        
        String value = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();
        
        if (!value.equals("=")) 
        {
            if (!operator.isEmpty()) 
                return;
            
            operator = value;
            num1 = Long.parseLong(result.getText());
            result.setText("");
            return;
            }
        else 
        {
            if (operator.isEmpty()) 
                return;
            num2 = Long.parseLong(result.getText());
            
            long output = model.calculate(num1, num2, operator);
            result.setText(String.valueOf(output));
            operator = "";
            start = true;
            
        }
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void Ac(ActionEvent event) {
        operator = "";
        start = true;
        result.setText(""); 
    }

}
```

****Here is the class that is doing the arithmetic :****

```
public class Calculation {

    public long calculate(long num1, long num2, String operator) 
    {
        switch (operator) 
        {
        case "+":
            return num1+num2;
        case "-":
            return num1-num2;
        case "*":
            return num1*num2;
        case "/":
            if(num2==0)
                return 0;
            return num1/num2;
        default:
            return 0 ;
        }
    
}

    
}
```

**Here is the fxml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="537.0" prefWidth="298.0" style="-fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainProcess">
   <children>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1C1C1C; -fx-background-radius: 30;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="result" alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" prefHeight="197.0" prefWidth="361.0" style="-fx-background-color: #af21611;" text="0" textFill="WHITE">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial" size="48.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10.0" vgap="10.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #D4D4D2;" text="+/-" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Arial" size="19.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #D4D4D2;" text="\%" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Arial" size="19.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: FF9500; -fx-background-radius: 30;" text="/" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="3">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #505050;" text="4" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #505050;" text="7" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #505050;" text="8" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #505050;" text="5" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #505050;" text="9" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #505050;" text="6" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: FF9500; -fx-background-radius: 30;" text="x" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: FF9500; -fx-background-radius: 30;" text="−" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Arial" size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #505050;" text="1" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #505050;" text="2" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #505050;" text="3" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: FF9500; -fx-background-radius: 30;" text="+" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" prefHeight="57.0" prefWidth="110.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #505050;" text="0" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #505050;" text="," textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-color: FF9500; -fx-background-radius: 30;" text="=" textFill="WHITE" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="27.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Ac" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="55.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 30; -fx-background-color: #D4D4D2;" text="AC">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="Arial" size="19.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Button>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Note that in my fxml, each button is associated to the right method, so the problem must come from the javafx code

** Sorry if the way of asking the question is not right, Ill take any good advice

Thanks!

Comment: Post the FXML. (Off topic: but why would you evaluate division by zero to zero?)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just edited . For the 0, when divise by 0, which is impossible, I want it to display 0. (It would be more logic to output error)

Comment: Multiplication doesn’t work for the obvious reason that the text in the button doesn’t match the text you’re testing for. I’m not sure why subtraction and division don’t work; I can test when I’m back at a computer. But matching by the text in the button is very fragile. It would be much better to have different handler methods for each operator, even if it’s slightly more verbose.

Comment: Showing zero for division by zero is just plain wrong.

Comment: I left my code for a few hours , came back and changer the multiplication operator and like by magic the / worked too. Only the - is giving me problem

Comment: Add some logging (e.g., `System.out.println` calls) at key points in your code, printing out values of parameters and such, in order to trace what is happening in your program. Or debug your code by placing breakpoints at key points and then stepping through the code to see what is happening. Either should help figure out the problem (I'd try out your code myself, but I don't have time just yet).

Comment: You also used a different symbol for subtraction: in FXML, you used U+2212 (minus sign), while in Calculation.class, it's a simple dash. Advise: using debugging and logs, you would probably have found this out yourself in a matter of minutes